# Where to find the sample (tutorial) applications that explain step-by-step of how to use php and java framework like the MVC Music Store of asp.net?

Tags: php, asp.net, spring, codeigniter, zend-framework

I have been learning different programming languages (Java, C#, PHP and Objective-C), and looking for a standard way of creating realistic applications using those languages. Recently, I found an excellent sample application using asp.net mvc named MVC Music Store from this site:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

It really helps me in creating an app in a standard way by putting everything of asp.net mvc into an realistic application, instead of creating some un-realistic or boring sample app like hello world or stuff like that. Now, I just wonder if there is any sample (tutorials) apps out there  similar to this app (MVC Music Store), but using different languages or framework like Java Spring or Zend (or CodeIgniter) framework to guide the learners of putting everything into a realistic app? Thank you so much.

Edit:

Actually, I have created some realistic projects using Java SE, Java EE, ASP.NET, Objective-C (iOS) and PHP. The thing is I just want to compare my style of programming with the professionals in order to improve my understanding. And I've seen not only in tons of books, but also in the university, they just teach the learners of how to do the small thing in each lesson, but do not teach them of how to put everything together into a big realistic project which I think can influence the rest of the learner coding's life.

I agree that there are a million samples out there, but as far as I know, there are only 3 sites that teach the learners to put every lesson into one realistic project: thenewboston: http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=51, TutsPlus site for building eCommerce with Laravel framework and the site I mentioned above. Hence, I think wasting of time is when the learners study every lesson, but do not know of how to apply them into a realistic project.

Comment: there are  a million samples, also know  as open-source software

Comment: my advice is to stop reading and code more, ask question as you progress, stop wasting time, start coding

Answer (score 0):

Quercus is an implementation of PHP interpreter with java language . you can put php code inside  of java code in servlet container . 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-quercus/index.html?ca=dat 
http://quercus.caucho.com/

**Update 1 :** 
java bridge : http://www.developer.com/java/other/php-with-java-using-php-java-bridge-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

This Java-Spring [web app](https://github.com/eewiki/simple-spring-webapp) is what I use as a minimalist MVC application for friends and students to pick up using Spring.

It is heavily based on Spring's demo projects and their reference documentation(http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) and I strongly recommend investing the time to learn it from the source but if you're just asking for quick example GET n POST with the basic annotations, it should do the job.